# Fortify throw inside finally bugs

Tags: java, exception, fortify

I am getting fortify issue as :
Poor Error Handling: Throw Inside Finally
I am not throwing exception inside finally block, but still it is showing this error.
Please find the code below.`

```
catch( IOException | JSONException | URISyntaxException e)
    {
        if(instream == null) {
            throw new  IOException("InputStream not valid");
        }
        return e.getMessage();
    }finally {
        if(instream != null ) {
            instream.close();
        }
        if(urlConnection != null ) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your concrete Exception and its stack trace. And if the exception occurs before your posted code, please add the complete code.

Comment: @Milgo you don't seem to understand the question. The problem isn't an exception or a stack trace. It's a linting (a code analyser that reports on potential bugs) warning. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are: `inStream.close()` can throw.

Generally, 'curing' the warning is actually going to make your code worse. This is the problem:

### *IF* the try block throws an uncaught exception

In this case, the finally block is executed. Let's say that the finally block runs `in.close();`. Especially if the entire reason we got here is that `in` got disconnected and started throwing IOEx, this is likely to also throw an IOEx. Any exceptions thrown out of a finally block 'overwrite' the exception that caused us to be here, and the stack trace from that close call is far less useful.

**So this is bad**.

We can fix it by wrapping the `in.close()` in your finally block in a `try { .. } catch (Exception ignore) {}`. But then, the other scenario is really bad:

### IF we get here 'normally'

It's possible for an input stream to work perfectly, and then when you close it, it throws. For a good long while common wisdom was 'eh, whatever, who cares, I got my data', but that's not a sensible idea: If an input's close ends up throwing, that probably means you didn't actually get all data yet, otherwise, why did it do that? So, now, silently swallowing any exceptions is a bad idea, and we want to throw it.

Without bending over backwards, using a boolean to track how we got to the finally block and depending on it, swallowing that exception or not, it is **not possible** to do it right.

Because this is so tricky, try-with-resources **actually does it right** and generates the requisite boilerplate.

Thus, the REAL solution: If you are closing resources in a finally block, don't. Use the `try (ResourceType r = new ResourceType()) { ... }` syntax instead.

If you truly can't do that, and you also can't make it work by creating a wrapper that is AutoClosable and will for example do nothing if the resource is null, then you're basically forced to tell your linter to stop complaining about this.